# How do I setup a private git repository in Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I use a git repository at work on GitHub. I know the basic commands for navigating and editing a repository but I don't know how to set one up from scratch.

I would like to setup my own server for the git repo so my buddies can come help me with the game I'm developing for Android. But I don't know how!

Would Gitosis be the best choice for this?

Comment: Using GitHub is not an option?

Comment: @Esko, GitHub is not an option because in order to make the repo private it requires $$$ and I'm looking for a free option.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org offers free private git and mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, You need to create the repo (easy as `git init`)
Second, You need to give your buddies access to the repo.

You may use few options which git handles:

- via `file://` (direct access on LAN)
- via ftp
- via git protocol (ssh access)

Third, manage the access, permissions etc.

For this, the best option is [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), better than `gitosis`. There is a good installation guide in the repo. The most tricky part is setting up passwordless access to the server (but this this is not actually git related). Using Ubuntu and Github you probably know what for are public ssh keys.

Gitolite is the best option so far, but a bit complex. However, if you don't want to use gitolite, you may still only to init the repo, and make the machine accessible, which is the simplest solution.

See also [Setting Up the Server](http://progit.org/book/ch4-4.html) from the free [Pro Git](http://progit.org/) book. There are chapters about *gitolite* and *gitosis* as well.

Answer (score 10):

IMO the simplest way is to use ssh.  If you have a machine that you and your buddies can all ssh to, then you just make a bare clone of your repository, put it up on the ssh server, and clone it from there.  I do this using my dreamhost account as the server.

```
cd my-repo
cd ..
# Make a bare copy of the repo
git clone --bare my-repo my-repo.git
# Upload the bare copy to the server
# -- in this case, I've already created a /repos folder to hold the bare repos
rsync my-repo.git/ mysshserver:/repos/my-repo.git/
# Add the new server repo as a remote to your local repository
cd my-repo
git remote add origin mysshserver:/repos/my-repo.git
```

Then for your buddies:

```
git clone mysshserver:/repos/my-repo.git/
```

The only trick is making sure all the user accounts you are using have write permissions to the repo folder (/repos/my-repo.git/* on the server).

Comment: Great advice, thanks. Did you really mean "git remote add master"? Or should that have been "git remote add origin"? (I'm new to git, so could be confused.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, probably should be origin.  Fixed in the answer.